# Minimize docker size in headless container along with node

Tags: node.js, docker, google-chrome

I want to install node inisde the chrome headless trunk image below:
alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk (https://hub.docker.com/r/alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk/).

The size of `alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk` is around 300MB, but after installing nodejs from source image size comes to around 900MB.

Installing node inside the docker:

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
```

Is there any way to minimize the size of `chrome-headless-trunk` image with node installation as well ?

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend using an alpine based image that is only 228MB and the tag I mentioned below has nodejs and chrome both. Your image is based on Ubuntu and its heavy as compared to alpine which is 5MB only.

```
FROM zenika/alpine-chrome

USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache tini make gcc g++ python git nodejs nodejs-npm yarn \
    && apk add --no-cache -X http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing wqy-zenhei \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /var/cache/apk/* \
    /usr/share/man \
    /tmp/*
USER chrome
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--"]
```

Docker image that has node and chrome

`zenika:with-node`

You check more details [alpine-chrome](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome) and [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/zenika/alpine-chrome)